# Como Converter RTF em HTML

Tags: php, html, rtf

Estou trabalhando em um sistema web que puxa um quadro de avisos de um sistema feito em Delphi, que usa o formato `RTF` para formatar o texto. Com isto preciso utilizar alguma classe Server-Side em PHP para transforma-lo em HTML.

A classe que estou tentando e a *rtfclass.php* que fica aqui: [rtfclass GitHub](https://github.com/mfn/rtfclass).

Não consegui encontrar uma documentação com exemplos para testa-lo com precisão.

Questões:

1. Qual é a melhor solução em conversão de RTF/HTML?
2. Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo do uso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou usar esse [**Parser**](http://www.websofia.com/2014/05/a-working-rtf-to-html-converter-in-php/)?

Inclua o arquivo *rtf.php* em algum lugar no seu projeto. Em seguida, faça o seguinte:

```
$reader = new RtfReader();
$rtf = file_get_contents("test.rtf"); // Ou uma string
$reader->Parse($rtf);
```

Se você quer ver o que está sendo analisado faça:

```
$reader->root->dump();
```

Para realizar a conversão para HTML:

```
$formatter = new RtfHtml();
echo $formatter->Format($reader->root);
```

Para salvar use alguma função que escreva no arquivo esse conteúdo em um arquivo, como [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php).

Segue como exemplo:

```
$html = $formatter->Format($reader->root);
file_put_contents('test.html', $html);
```

O arquivo *rtf.php*:

```
/**
   * RTF parser/formatter
   *
   * This code reads RTF files and formats the RTF data to HTML.
   *
   * PHP version 5
   *
   * @author     Alexander van Oostenrijk
   * @copyright  2014 Alexander van Oostenrijk
   * @license    GNU
   * @version    1
   * @link       http://www.websofia.com
   * 
   * Sample of use:
   * 
   * $reader = new RtfReader();
   * $rtf = file_get_contents("itc.rtf"); // or use a string
   * $reader->Parse($rtf);
   * //$reader->root->dump(); // to see what the reader read
   * $formatter = new RtfHtml();
   * echo $formatter->Format($reader->root);   
   */

  class RtfElement
  {
    protected function Indent($level)
    {
      for($i = 0; $i < $level * 2; $i++) echo "&nbsp;";
    }
  }

  class RtfGroup extends RtfElement
  {
    public $parent;
    public $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->parent = null;
      $this->children = array();
    }

    public function GetType()
    {
      // No children?
      if(sizeof($this->children) == 0) return null;
      // First child not a control word?
      $child = $this->children[0];
      if(get_class($child) != "RtfControlWord") return null;
      return $child->word;
    }    

    public function IsDestination()
    {
      // No children?
      if(sizeof($this->children) == 0) return null;
      // First child not a control symbol?
      $child = $this->children[0];
      if(get_class($child) != "RtfControlSymbol") return null;
      return $child->symbol == '*';
    }

    public function dump($level = 0)
    {
      echo "<div>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "{";
      echo "</div>";

      foreach($this->children as $child)
      {
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfGroup")
        {
          if ($child->GetType() == "fonttbl") continue;
          if ($child->GetType() == "colortbl") continue;
          if ($child->GetType() == "stylesheet") continue;
          if ($child->GetType() == "info") continue;
          // Skip any pictures:
          if (substr($child->GetType(), 0, 4) == "pict") continue;
          if ($child->IsDestination()) continue;
        }
        $child->dump($level + 2);
      }

      echo "<div>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "}";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  }

  class RtfControlWord extends RtfElement
  {
    public $word;
    public $parameter;

    public function dump($level)
    {
      echo "<div style='color:green'>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "WORD {$this->word} ({$this->parameter})";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  }

  class RtfControlSymbol extends RtfElement
  {
    public $symbol;
    public $parameter = 0;

    public function dump($level)
    {
      echo "<div style='color:blue'>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "SYMBOL {$this->symbol} ({$this->parameter})";
      echo "</div>";
    }    
  }

  class RtfText extends RtfElement
  {
    public $text;

    public function dump($level)
    {
      echo "<div style='color:red'>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "TEXT {$this->text}";
      echo "</div>";
    }    
  }

  class RtfReader
  {
    public $root = null;

    protected function GetChar()
    {
      $this->char = $this->rtf[$this->pos++];
    }

    protected function ParseStartGroup()
    {
      // Store state of document on stack.
      $group = new RtfGroup();
      if($this->group != null) $group->parent = $this->group;
      if($this->root == null)
      {
        $this->group = $group;
        $this->root = $group;
      }
      else
      {
        array_push($this->group->children, $group);
        $this->group = $group;
      }
    }

    protected function is_letter()
    {
      if(ord($this->char) >= 65 && ord($this->char) <= 90) return TRUE;
      if(ord($this->char) >= 90 && ord($this->char) <= 122) return TRUE;
      return FALSE;
    }

    protected function is_digit()
    {
      if(ord($this->char) >= 48 && ord($this->char) <= 57) return TRUE;
      return FALSE;
    }

    protected function ParseEndGroup()
    {
      // Retrieve state of document from stack.
      $this->group = $this->group->parent;
    }

    protected function ParseControlWord()
    {
      $this->GetChar();
      $word = "";
      while($this->is_letter())
      {
        $word .= $this->char;
        $this->GetChar();
      }

      // Read parameter (if any) consisting of digits.
      // Paramater may be negative.
      $parameter = null;
      $negative = false;
      if($this->char == '-') 
      {
        $this->GetChar();
        $negative = true;
      }
      while($this->is_digit())
      {
        if($parameter == null) $parameter = 0;
        $parameter = $parameter * 10 + $this->char;
        $this->GetChar();
      }
      if($parameter === null) $parameter = 1;
      if($negative) $parameter = -$parameter;

      // If this is \u, then the parameter will be followed by 
      // a character.
      if($word == "u") 
      {
      }
      // If the current character is a space, then
      // it is a delimiter. It is consumed.
      // If it's not a space, then it's part of the next
      // item in the text, so put the character back.
      else
      {
        if($this->char != ' ') $this->pos--; 
      }

      $rtfword = new RtfControlWord();
      $rtfword->word = $word;
      $rtfword->parameter = $parameter;
      array_push($this->group->children, $rtfword);
    }

    protected function ParseControlSymbol()
    {
      // Read symbol (one character only).
      $this->GetChar();
      $symbol = $this->char;

      // Symbols ordinarily have no parameter. However, 
      // if this is \', then it is followed by a 2-digit hex-code:
      $parameter = 0;
      if($symbol == '\'')
      {
        $this->GetChar(); 
        $parameter = $this->char;
        $this->GetChar(); 
        $parameter = hexdec($parameter . $this->char);
      }

      $rtfsymbol = new RtfControlSymbol();
      $rtfsymbol->symbol = $symbol;
      $rtfsymbol->parameter = $parameter;
      array_push($this->group->children, $rtfsymbol);
    }

    protected function ParseControl()
    {
      // Beginning of an RTF control word or control symbol.
      // Look ahead by one character to see if it starts with
      // a letter (control world) or another symbol (control symbol):
      $this->GetChar();
      $this->pos--;
      if($this->is_letter()) 
        $this->ParseControlWord();
      else
        $this->ParseControlSymbol();
    }

    protected function ParseText()
    {
      // Parse plain text up to backslash or brace,
      // unless escaped.
      $text = "";

      do
      {
        $terminate = false;
        $escape = false;

        // Is this an escape?
        if($this->char == '\\')
        {
          // Perform lookahead to see if this
          // is really an escape sequence.
          $this->GetChar();
          switch($this->char)
          {
            case '\\': $text .= '\\'; break;
            case '{': $text .= '{'; break;
            case '}': $text .= '}'; break;
            default:
              // Not an escape. Roll back.
              $this->pos = $this->pos - 2;
              $terminate = true;
              break;
          }
        }
        else if($this->char == '{' || $this->char == '}')
        {
          $this->pos--;
          $terminate = true;
        }

        if(!$terminate && !$escape)
        {
          $text .= $this->char;
          $this->GetChar();
        }
      }
      while(!$terminate && $this->pos < $this->len);

      $rtftext = new RtfText();
      $rtftext->text = $text;
      array_push($this->group->children, $rtftext);
    }

    public function Parse($rtf)
    {
      $this->rtf = $rtf;
      $this->pos = 0;
      $this->len = strlen($this->rtf);
      $this->group = null;
      $this->root = null;

      while($this->pos < $this->len)
      {
        // Read next character:
        $this->GetChar();

        // Ignore \r and \n
        if($this->char == "\n" || $this->char == "\r") continue;

        // What type of character is this?
        switch($this->char)
        {
          case '{':
            $this->ParseStartGroup();
            break;
          case '}':
            $this->ParseEndGroup();
            break;
          case '\\':
            $this->ParseControl();
            break;
          default:
            $this->ParseText();
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class RtfState
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->Reset();
    }

    public function Reset()
    {
      $this->bold = false;
      $this->italic = false;
      $this->underline = false;
      $this->end_underline = false;
      $this->strike = false;
      $this->hidden = false;
      $this->fontsize = 0;
    }
  }

  class RtfHtml
  {
    public function Format($root)
    {
      $this->output = "";
      // Create a stack of states:
      $this->states = array();
      // Put an initial standard state onto the stack:
      $this->state = new RtfState();
      array_push($this->states, $this->state);
      $this->FormatGroup($root);
      return $this->output;
    }

    protected function FormatGroup($group)
    {
      // Can we ignore this group?
      if ($group->GetType() == "fonttbl") return;
      if ($group->GetType() == "colortbl") return;
      if ($group->GetType() == "stylesheet") return;
      if ($group->GetType() == "info") return;
      // Skip any pictures:
      if (substr($group->GetType(), 0, 4) == "pict") return;
      if ($group->IsDestination()) return;

      // Push a new state onto the stack:
      $this->state = clone $this->state;
      array_push($this->states, $this->state);

      foreach($group->children as $child)
      {
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfGroup") $this->FormatGroup($child);
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfControlWord") $this->FormatControlWord($child);
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfControlSymbol") $this->FormatControlSymbol($child);
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfText") $this->FormatText($child);
      }

      // Pop state from stack.
      array_pop($this->states);
      $this->state = $this->states[sizeof($this->states)-1];
    }

    protected function FormatControlWord($word)
    {
      if($word->word == "plain") $this->state->Reset();
      if($word->word == "b") $this->state->bold = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "i") $this->state->italic = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "ul") $this->state->underline = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "ulnone") $this->state->end_underline = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "strike") $this->state->strike = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "v") $this->state->hidden = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "fs") $this->state->fontsize = ceil(($word->parameter / 24) * 16);

      if($word->word == "par") $this->output .= "<p>";

      // Characters:
      if($word->word == "lquote") $this->output .= "&lsquo;";
      if($word->word == "rquote") $this->output .= "&rsquo;";
      if($word->word == "ldblquote") $this->output .= "&ldquo;";
      if($word->word == "rdblquote") $this->output .= "&rdquo;";
      if($word->word == "emdash") $this->output .= "&mdash;";
      if($word->word == "endash") $this->output .= "&ndash;";
      if($word->word == "bullet") $this->output .= "&bull;";
      if($word->word == "u") $this->output .= "&loz;";
    }

    protected function BeginState()
    {
      $span = "";
      if($this->state->bold) $span .= "font-weight:bold;";
      if($this->state->italic) $span .= "font-style:italic;";
      if($this->state->underline) $span .= "text-decoration:underline;";
      if($this->state->end_underline) $span .= "text-decoration:none;";
      if($this->state->strike) $span .= "text-decoration:strikethrough;";
      if($this->state->hidden) $span .= "display:none;";
      if($this->state->fontsize != 0) $span .= "font-size: {$this->state->fontsize}px;";
      $this->output .= "<span style='{$span}'>";
    }

    protected function EndState()
    {
      $this->output .= "</span>";
    }

    protected function FormatControlSymbol($symbol)
    {
      if($symbol->symbol == '\'')
      {
        $this->BeginState();
        $this->output .= htmlentities(chr($symbol->parameter), ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');
        $this->EndState();
      }
    }

    protected function FormatText($text)
    {
      $this->BeginState();
      $this->output .= $text->text;
      $this->EndState();
    }
  }
```

**Atualização**

Antes de fazer o *Parsing* verifique se o conteúdo a ser convertido indica ter o formato *.rtf*, com uma expressão regular podemos ver se uma sequência têm alguns traços desse formato:

```php
$texto = '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}';

if (preg_match("/(\{\})|}|(\\\S+)/", $texto) > 0) {
  // $texto parece ter o formato .rtf
} else {
  // $texto parece ser texto puro
}
```

Se o texto estiver no formato *.rtf* você faz o *parsing* caso contrário retorne o texto puro.

Comment: Testei essa solução, e funcionou, porém existe mais um caso, ele identifica se é rtf e transforma em html, tudo bem, mas se eu enviar um texto sem puro sem rtf ele não trâs nenhuma informação. acontece que, para o delphi que cria avisos em rtf eu preciso converter, mas no sistema web eu crio avisos em texto puro com algumas quebras de linha, preciso que retorne uma string de texto caso nao seja rtf

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Nesse caso você teria adaptar a função `Parse` para atender isso. Como você está chamando `Parse`?

Comment: Deixo  a class em um arquivo rtf.php do um include  após isto faço um select  na tabela avisos e coloco o resultado em uma variável  que coloco em vez do arquivo e pego o texto  em html com outra variável e mostro na tela

Comment: Para postar o código apenas amanhã porque não estou mais no serviço :(

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Atualizei a resposta, antes de fazer o *parse* veja se o texto têm o formato *.rtf* se não tiver retorne o texto puro.